# How to configure docker-compose.yml to use passbolt with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker with WSL2 on a Debian VM and i'm trying to install passbolt.

I follow the steps on this guide : https://help.passbolt.com/hosting/install/ce/docker.html.

When i run docker-compose up, it's working and i can reach the database with telnet but it's impossible to reach the instance of passbolt with telnet and with my browser.

It's strange because the two containers: mariadb and passbolt are running.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
    version: '3.4'
    services:
      db:
        image: mariadb:10.3
        env_file:
          - env/mysql.env
        volumes:
          - database_volume:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    
      passbolt:
        image: passbolt/passbolt:latest-ce
        #Alternatively you can use rootless:
        #image: passbolt/passbolt:latest-ce-non-root
        tty: true
        container_name: passbolt
        restart: always
    
        depends_on:
          - db
        env_file:
          - env/passbolt.env
        volumes:
          - gpg_volume:/etc/passbolt/gpg
          - images_volume:/usr/share/php/passbolt/webroot/img/public
        command: ["/usr/bin/wait-for.sh", "-t", "0", "db:3306", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
        #Alternatively for non-root images:
        # - 80:8080
        # - 443:4433
    volumes:
      database_volume:
      gpg_volume:
      images_volume:
```

If anybody can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose file looks quite ordinary and I don't see any issues.
Can you please attach your passbolt.env and mysql.env (remove any important information ofcourse).
Also, the passbolt.conf (VirtualHost) might be useful.
Make sure that the DNS A record is valid and that you have no firewall blocks.
Error logs will be appreciated aswell.